# JPA circular reference. "object references an unsaved transient instance"

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, many-to-one

I'm using JPA / Hibernate.

Let's say I have folders and files.
Every folder can contain more folders and files.
Every file knows what its root folder is (not the parent).

```
@Entity
public class Folder{
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn("folder_id")
    private List<Folder> folders;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn("file_id")
    private List<File> files;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class File {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    private Folder rootFolder;

    ...
}
```

I create a new file and a new folder. I put the file in the folder.
Now the file is in the folders "files"-collection and the folder is referenced in the files "rootFolder"-variable.

If I persist this, I get the "object references an unsaved transient instance" or "save the transient instance before flushing: entities.file.rootFolder -> entities.Category" (depends on what gets persisted first).

There hast to be a way I can annotate this, so it will work not matter what I save first!?
I could work around it somehow programmatically to insert first one Entity without referencing the other, then insert the other and then put in the reference, but I don't think that that should be neccessary here.

I searched for this, but all I could find was @OneToMany combined with @ManyToOne, but in my case I can't use it. A folder shouldn't know if it is a root folder.

I'd appreciate any thoughts or directions to tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem with those mappings or with the scenario you describe, assuming it all occurs within one transaction, or, more accurately, with no flushing in between. The errors you describe *only* happen upon flush, which typically happens upon transaction commit. It even tells you in the error, "save the transient instance before flushing". What's disallowed is flushing a partially-saved object graph. As long as all objects in a graph are saved before the flush happens, you're fine.

I've created a working example on Github based on your code. You can [browse the code](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/stackoverflow/14921963-hibernate-circular-reference) and/or clone the project and run it with:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp/stackoverflow/14921963-hibernate-circular-reference
mvn -q compile exec:java -D exec.mainClass=com.foo.Main
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
An additional problem is, that I already have modules to save these objects (and I need to use them). Is there a way to manually wrap a Transaction around them or something?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you persist both objects within the same transaction.

However, in the relationship between files and folders, you're incorrectly marking the owner. The many-to-one side should [almost always be the owner of the relationship](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/). Therefore, the correct way would be:

```
@Entity
public class File {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "folder_id") // this table has a foreign key
  private Folder rootFolder;
}

@Entity
public class Folder {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rootFolder") // 'File' is the owner of this relationship
  private List<File> files;
}
```

Similarly, in `Folder`, it should be just:

```
@OneToMany 
private List<Folder> folders;
```

Or, you may go with a bi-directional relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Folder {
  @ManyToOne
  private Folder parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private List<Folder> folders;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: OP already stated that a file's root folder isn't its parent. Therefore, Folder.files isn't mapped by File.rootFolder.